# how to update data in tableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I initialize data in my table with an array in `viewDidLoad` and then add the data to the cell. This a standard way of doing it that I read in a book.
This is what I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Create array and add data ("tableViewValues" is initialized in .h file)
    tableViewValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [tableViewValues addObject:@"$280,000.00"];
    [tableViewValues addObject:@"$279,318.79"];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSString *cellValue = [tableViewValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

    return cell;
}
```

So when the view loads, those two currency values are in my table.
Now in another function, I populate a another array with different currency numbers depending on what the user enter in a textfield. How would I update my current table view and replace those values with the values in my other array? Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can call

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

to reload all data, however, you will need to program a way to have the array that you want populate the table. Maybe you want your -cellForRowAtIndexPath to call a private method that conditionally picks the correct array.

Comment: i got the reload data to work, thanks. But I'm having trouble populating each cell with values in my array? Could u you elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: It depends. Do you need the initial values back after you get the new values? What is your table updating values on. Hard to say without more info.

Comment: i have a textfield delegate "shouldChangeCharactersInRange" and I fill an array with numbers in that method. So the array is changing constantly. I don't care about the old values. I just want to take my array values and place the into the table every time the method is called.

Comment: Then in that method just replace the old tableViewArray with the new values. You might want to make tableViewValues a property and then call the setter on it by calling self.tableViewValues which will take care of releasing the old one and retaining the new values

Comment: I must be missing something because the data is not updated. I print out my tableView array to make sure it has the numbers I want and it does. But when I call [self.myOwnTableView reloadData];, nothing happens. I'm confused haha.

Comment: If you email me your tableView .h and .m file I will have a look at it for you, if you like.

Comment: i now get it to work in one method but not in another. i"ll figure it out, it must be minor. thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi I have placed one tableview query. Can you check and answer this one also on following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239543/tableview-is-not-showing-data

Comment: I've had this problem many times and I always make the same mistake. [self._tableview reloadData] works. The question is the place where you populate the table. I did it in -(void)viewDidLoad and the table was updated with the same data. Update the content (plist, dictionary, array, whatever) in the same place where you call reloadData, just before. THAT IS THE KEY!!!

Answer (score 3):

You have to remove all values from your array then you have to call table reload data

```
// In the method where you will get new values
[tableViewValues removeAllObjects];  
[tableViewValues add:@"new values"];  
 //reload table view with new values
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Same question. Does this add anything new? Because it is basically the same answer as the one that is already accepted.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem many times and I always make the same mistake.

**`[self._tableview reloadData]` works!**

The question is the place where you populate the table.

I did it in -(void)viewDidLoad and the table was **updated** with the **same data**. Apparently nothing happens.

Update the content of your table view (plist, dictionary, array, whatever) in the same place where you call [self._tableview reloadData], just before.

**THAT IS THE KEY!!!**

Do a test:

```
#pragma mark - Actions

- (IBAction)refreshParams:(id)sender {

   self.dictionary = nil;

   [self._tableView reloadData];
}
```

You can see how disappear the tableview content when you push the refresh button. Obviously, this is an example. I use a dictionary to populate the table and a button to refresh the content.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to (release and) recreate same `tableViewValues` array and then call `reloadData` method on tableView like this:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

This will work if you're on table view controller and `self.tableView` points to the table in question.

Answer (score 2):

in that function, after assigning values to the new array, all you have to do is

```
 [tableViewValues removeAllObjects];
 tableViewValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:newArray];
 [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

will help you for this.

Answer (score 1):

### In Swift,

`tableView.reloadData()` or `self.tableView.reloadData()`, where `tableView` is a property in your ViewController.