# TableView is not showing data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have place this question before on following link with code & screenshot.

[TableView is not loading data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103034/tableview-is-not-loading-data)

Now I came to know my tableview is loading data in tableview cell but not showing/displaying it. I have one Model View Controller in my project. The ModelView controller get called from Mapviewcontroller screen through Search Button. After resigning the Model view controller I can see the data in tableview. (It means when I move to next controller and back to previous tableview.. my tableview shows data in it.)

Here I my data get visible in tableview only after resigning the modelview controller.....
Everything works fine. I just want to know how should I display the tableview data as soon as web-service get called on first screen itself???

Comment: I hope my question is clear and understandable

Comment: I have edited few lines for understanding my question well....help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `[_tableView reloadData];` at the end of the method that calls the web-service, or the one that populates the `markers` array.

Comment: Superb Its working. Wow this problem was pending since 3 weeks. Many thanks Louis

Answer (score 0):

If you are manipulating table data in an asynchronous **Block**,
pass a reference of the tableview to the method implementing the block, and remember to call

```
[tableview reloadData];
```

within the block, and not out outside